# How does a view know its own url in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4, view

Is there some easy way (offered by rails?) for the view to know its own url ? The one that was called to display the page.

I am able to write a helper method that will rebuild the url from the different parameters available for the controller in the params hash. But before programming such method, i was wondering if there is anything standard already.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.fullpath` or even `request.original_url`.

Take a look at [the request object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which rails version you are using :

Rails 2 : request.url

Rails 3 and above : request.original_url -- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url